# How to compare two one hot encoded data frames based on column names?

Tags: python, data-mining, data, data-science-model, mathematics

I have two datasets with shapes (329, 159) and  (26,24). Both of them are one-hot encoded. The columns in the smaller dataset are present in the larger dataset. The smaller dataset has scores that I need to apply to the larger dataset.

For example: if the gender of a dataset is M in the larger dataset then according to the smaller dataset, it should get 0.80 as a score. How do I compare these two datasets and assign scores?

Comment: It will be difficult to arrive at a conclusion without knowing the structure of both the datasets and also how you want to score the samples. It would be nice if you could add some more details regarding your problem and the dataset,

Comment: Makes sense! 
Dataset one has columns like gender M, gender F, age 65+, age 55-64, location, etc. Dataset two has the same columns but not all are included - only the ones that are scored are included. Like if the person is 65+ then the score for his age is 0.69. If his location is texas then his score will change to 0.69 + 0.30. Like that for 15 attributes. I would copy paste the dataset but then its pretty huge number of columns. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: The smaller dataset is already scored. The new one should be scored depending on the scores in smaller dataset.

Comment: You can paste some 5/6 samples from both datasets in a text file and add links to them in your question.